# Check if tab was added to TabControl.TabPages

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wrapper, tabcontrol

I am trying to make a wrapper for a TabControl, does anyone know how to listen for when a tab has been added to TabControl.TabPages?

Regards,
Jordan

Comment: on what? I simply want to know how to listen for when a Tab has been added to TabControl.TabPages

Comment: what do you want to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook to the TabPages' parent, which is the TabControl, and hook onto its `ControlAdded` event, and then check to see if that control's type is a TabPage. So something like this:

```
private void tabControl1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(TabPage)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Yippee!"); // Insert code here
    }
}
```

Just remember the event goes on the TabControl, not the TabPage

Comment: Alright thanks, but I believe that only checks for when a control is added to a tab

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `ControlAdded` event that you can try and hook into

Comment: I believe that only checks for when a control is added to a tab